# How do I mount an NFS share on an CM 12?

Tags: networking, kernel, shell

I'd like to mount an NFS share on my Android cell phone, with perhaps a mount-unmount button on the home screen. Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

My `/system/lib/modules` is empty. It doesn't have `nfs.ko`.

Answer (score -1):

There are many apps that can do this:

- [Mount Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twimager.cifsmanager)
- [CifsManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ws.plattner.cifsmanager)

And also [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=718719) thread on XDA-Developers suggest using BusyBox (it's simpler to just open the thread on go trough the discussion than for me to copy that stuff here, you'd need context to understand)

Finally, this research was done by a simple Google search, you should do your research before posting.

Comment: Neither work. Tried both.

Comment: Do you have BusyBox installed?

Comment: Yes. As, it comes installed with CM12.

Comment: Neither of the apps is available anymore :(